# OrderBy expression with AutoQuery?

Tags: servicestack

Is it possible to create an AutoQuery with a SQL expression for OrderBy?

```
public class FindStatisticalData : QueryDb<StatisticalData>
{ }   

public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; }
var query = new FindStatisticalData();
query.OrderBy = "iif(report_period=0,0,iif(report_period=1,1,iif(report_period=2,3,iif(report_period=3,2,report_period))))";
var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(query, Request, db);

// EXCEPTION thrown:  Could not find field (iif(report_period=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only fields can be ordered in the `OrderBy` on the AutoQuery Request DTO.

You can try ordering by an expression in the populated `SqlExpression<T>` using `UnsafeOrderBy()`, e.g:

```cs
var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(query, Request, db);
q.UnsafeOrderBy(...);
```